# Transferwise regulated by RBI India

Tags: india, international-transfer, wire-transfer, legal

According to RBI FEMA Act Section 10, only authorized person or company could transfer Forex from India.

I have checked the website of Transferwise and can't find any information on this. How can I make sure that Trasnferwise is an authorized company by RBI?

Comment: From https://transferwise.com/help/article/1663577/indian-rupee-transfers/transfers-to-inr : 'We can currently only send money to India, and not receive deposits from India.'

Comment: I think that page is not updated. See https://transferwise.com/help/article/2962281/indian-rupee-transfers/transfers-from-inr

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything. The page you linked only talks about transfers in INR, which is consistent with what I linked to.